# Java код выполняется не последовательно

Tags: java, android-studio

Такая проблема: вызываются две функции (одна идет за другой), но первой выполняется вторая, что делает программу не юзабельной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            adapter.sortExpenseList(checkFilterType(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()), typeSort);
            runLayoutAnimation(recyclerView);
        }

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            /****/
            Log.e("ERA", "11");
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredExpenseList = (ArrayList<Expense>) results.values;
            Log.e("ERA", "1");
        }
    };
}

public void sortExpenseList(String filterType, final String sortType) {
    Log.e("ERA", "2");
    switch (filterType) {
        case FILTER_BY_DATE:
            /****/
            break;

        case FILTER_BY_MILEAGE:
            /****/
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: А как ожидалось? И что давало надежду на такое ожидание?

Comment: а вы попробуйте `adapter.getFilter()` заменить на `getFilter()`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Сначала вызываю adapter.getFilter(), затем adapter.sortExpenseList. Или я что-то не так понимаю? Код написан последовательно и должен вызываться последовательно, разе нет?
Получается, что ответ приходит от второй строки, а только потом от первой. Можно ли как то выполнять данные строки последовательно?

Comment: @Рустам `getFilter` создает объект-наследник класса `Filter`. А когда у этого объекта будут вызваны методы `performFiltering` и `publishResults` из кода не видно

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Спасибо за помощь!